# How do I send mail to selected persons from a group in Lotus Notes?

Tags: email, lotus-notes

I want to send an email to particular friends from the group I created. I think that I saw a feature where Lotus Notes displays the list of members from that group and we select, which ones we want to include. How do I enable that?

Scenario: One of my friends (who is included in my friend list group) sends a mail only to me. I want to forward that to other friend in group but omitting his and some other people's names. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.notes85.help.doc/con_use_group_to_address_t.html
In short - in "Delivery Options" you can remove the "Do not expand personal groups" option and then edit the names.

This (copied from Notes R6 Help) may also help:
"In the open message, with the cursor in the field that contains the list name, choose View - Refresh. Then edit the list of names. Keep in mind that any changes are used for only this message, not saved in the list document."

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read this in help but didn't understand.it is expanding the list though and i need to delete the names that i wanted. What i saw was it gives me list of names with checkboxes selected with all names and to whom i dont want to send mail i will deselect it. Is there any feature like that(somewhat similar i saw that is why i am asking but cant ask that person as he is not in my contact now)??

Comment: I can't recall using similar dialog with checkboxes. Maybe it is a feature that wasn't available in the mail I've used. I would add that you can also remove names using the "Address" dialog, but I see this is not as quick and straightforward as the dialog you described.